# how to get error message from contract modifier in UI?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

When testing a contract on Remix I notice if a method does not pass a modifier you actually see the error message shown in the window below the contract code. Is this something I can get from web3, or how can I in my own UI get this error messages from the contract when provided?

Here is a simple contract:

```
address public owner;

modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == owner, "Owner account is required");
    _;
}

constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
}

function doStuff()
external
view
onlyOwner
returns (bool) {
    return true;
}
```

When I call the contract not from `owner` in remix, in the console I get this message:

> call to Contract.doStuff errored: VM error: revert.
> revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
> Reason provided by the contract: "Owner account is required". Debug the transaction to get more information.

Is the error it gives something I can get from a web3 transaction? I do not see it

Comment: Well, you didn't specify which client you're using. Support hasn't been added for web3js yet: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1707. If you're interested in using the Java version, that client is updated even less frequently.

Comment: @AdamKipnis Oh intersting. I am just doing local testing on the Remix Javascript VM. Are they providing that error message string from a Java server then?

Comment: You mean the Java client? I don’t believe so, but I haven’t tested it yet. The error message support was only added to Solidity with 0.4.22.